# Wordpress: custom field display twice

Tags: wordpress, field

I have a little bug on my WordPress...

When I added a custom field, I have no ajax, I need to saved the draft or publish to see the update.

And after I saved my post, the custom field display twice.

```
name :   Steffi

name :   Steffi
```

Help, please ! Thanks

Comment: You may be better off asking this at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to change the php variable in this sample code:

```
<?php
    $cf_video = 'video_code';
    $video_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $cf_video, true);

    echo ($video_meta);
?>
```

there are more about this in http://monstertut.com/2012/06/wordpress-custom-field-template/

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys, I found **THE** solution.

Problems :

- Custom field display twice.
- No Ajax/jQuery visual feedback.

If you've been working on the file `function.php`, make sure you remove extra line breaks.

Particularly at the top and the bottom of your file... If you have some line breaks, your xml got an error : `XML or text declaration not at start of entity`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but hopefully this will help someone else with this issue.

I personally found that removing the closing php tag (`?>`) from the end of my functions.php file resolved this issue.